# Changing enum to next value [C++11]

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement

What I want to do is to use enum to specify different draw modes easily. So far this is what I've got:

```
class Grid {
   enum drawMode { GRID, EROSION, RIVERS, HUMIDITY, ATMOSPHERE }
   drawMode activeDraw;

   void draw() {
      switch(activeDraw) {
      case GRID:
         drawGrid();
         break;
      case EROSION:
         drawErosion();
         break;
      // etc..
   }

   void keyPressed(int key) {
      switch(key) {
      case ' ':
         // Cycle activeDraw to next drawMode
      }
}
```

So if user hits spacebar the activeDraw will change to next value from enum. So if the current activeDraw is GRID after hitting space it will change to EROSION and if activeDraw is ATMOSPHERE it will change to GRID.
Is there a simple solution to this?
Thanks.

Comment: How is this question related to C++11 ? I suggest using `enum class` would have qualified this question for C++11.

Comment: It is related because in C++11 you have to manually cast it in order to work with it as an integer and that's the main point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted by Maroš Beťko, to add 1 to a variable, you have to cast the value to `int` and back:

```
activeDraw = static_cast<drawMode>(static_cast<int>(activeDraw) + 1);
```

If the enum is defined without the C++11 `enum class` syntax (like in the question's text), the casting to `int` is not necessary:

```
activeDraw = static_cast<drawMode>(activeDraw + 1);
```

To make it cycle back to zero, use integer arithmetic, modulo operator:

```
activeDraw = static_cast<drawMode>((activeDraw + 1) % (ATMOSPHERE + 1));
```

To eliminate one ugly `+1`, add another element to the enum:

```
enum drawMode { ..., ATMOSPHERE, NUM_DRAW_MODES };
...
activeDraw = static_cast<drawMode>((activeDraw + 1) % NUM_DRAW_MODES);
```

You can also stuff this code into a `operator++` if you use it very often:

```
drawMode operator++(drawMode& mode)
{
    mode = static_cast<drawMode>((mode + 1) % NUM_DRAW_MODES);
    return mode;
}

drawMode operator++(drawMode& mode, int) // postfix operator
{
    drawMode result = mode;
    ++mode;
    return result;
}
```

Overloading operators for `enum`s is rarely used, and some people consider it overkill (bad), but it will make your code shorter (and arguably cleaner).

Comment: Just be aware that the modulo operator is very slow and in this case overkill. You only need to check if the new value is `NUM_DRAW_MODES`, and if it is, bring it back to zero. Modulo is better used if you actually might end up moving past the end of a list by more than one step.

Comment: The compiler will likely optimize out the modulo operation.

Answer (score 7):

Since your enumerates don't have a forced value, you could "increase" them, and perform a modulo on the last item + 1 to reset to the first one when needed:

```
 activeDraw = drawMode((activeDraw+1) % (ATMOSPHERE+1));
```

BTW: also works in C language with a slight modification:

```
activeDraw = (activeDraw+1) % (ATMOSPHERE+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something you should write once, use many places.

`boost` has some operator libraries that might be useful.  If you need to write your own, here is an example:

```
namespace EnumOps {
  // ADL helper.  See #define below for macro that writes
  // the "this enum should use enum ops" overload:
  template<class T>
  std::false_type use_enum_ops_f(T&&){return {};}

  // trait class that detects if we should be messing with this enum:
  template<class T>
  using use_enum_ops = decltype(use_enum_ops_f( std::declval<T>() ));

  // to-from underlying type:
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  constexpr std::underlying_type_t<E> get_underlying(E e) {
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  constexpr E from_underlying(std::underlying_type_t<E> e) {
    return static_cast<E>(e);
  }

  // Clamps your Enum value from 0 to E::MAX_VALUE using modular arithmetic
  // You must include a MAX_VALUE in your enum.
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E clamp_max( std::underlying_type_t<E> e ) {
    constexpr auto max = get_underlying(E::MAX_VALUE);
    if (e < 0) {
      auto count = -(e-max+1)/max;
      e =  e + count*max;
    }
    return from_underlying<E>(e % max);
  }

  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E& operator+=( E& e, std::underlying_type_t<E> x ) {
    e= clamp_max<E>(get_underlying(e) + x);
    return e;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E& operator-=( E& e, std::underlying_type_t<E> x ) {
    e= clamp_max<E>(get_underlying(e) - x);
    return e;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E operator+( E e, std::underlying_type_t<E> x ) {
    return e+=x;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E operator+( std::underlying_type_t<E> x, E e ) {
    return e+=x;
  }
  // no int - enum permitted, but enum-int is:
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E operator-( E e, std::underlying_type_t<E> x ) {
    e -= x;
    return e;
  }
  // enum-enum returns the distance between them:
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  std::underlying_type_t<E> operator-( E lhs, E rhs ) {
    return get_underlying(lhs) - get_underlying(rhs);
  }
  // ++ and -- support:
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E& operator++( E& lhs ) {
    lhs += 1;
    return lhs;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E operator++( E& lhs, int ) {
    auto tmp = lhs;
    ++lhs;
    return tmp;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E& operator--( E& lhs ) {
    lhs -= 1;
    return lhs;
  }
  template<class E,
    std::enable_if_t< use_enum_ops<E>{}, int> =0
  >
  E operator--( E& lhs, int ) {
    auto tmp = lhs;
    --lhs;
    return tmp;
  }
}
// use this macro in the namespace of your enum
// passing it your enun name:
#define ENABLE_ENUM_OPS(...) \
  std::true_type use_enum_ops_f(__VA_ARGS__){return {};}
// Where you wnat to use ops, you must also
// using namespace EnumOps;
```

Example use:

```
namespace somewhere {
  enum class bob { A, B, C, MAX_VALUE };
  ENABLE_ENUM_OPS(bob)
}

int main() {
  using namespace EnumOps;
  auto x = somewhere::bob::A;
  ++x;
  std::cout << (x == somewhere::bob::B) << "\n";
  x+=3;
  std::cout << (x == somewhere::bob::B) << "\n";
  x-=4;
  std::cout << (x == somewhere::bob::A) << "\n";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a80e86623fb7319).

This uses modest amount of C++14 -- the `std::underlying_type_t<E>`.  Replace with `typename std::underlying_type<E>::type`.  And similar for any other `_t` aliases I sneaked in.

It uses C++11 features that MSVC 2015 fails at miserably.  Use a C++11 compiler to fix that problem.  It may appear to initially work in MSVC 2015, but do not be fooled.  I have not tried it on MSVC 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are esentially just named integers, so you can treat them as such.

If you add a `NUM_DRAW_MODES` value to the end of the enum to keep track of the count, then this should work:

```
void keyPressed(int key) {
  switch(key) {
  case ' ':
    // Cycle activeDraw to next drawMode
    ++activeDraw;
    if (activeDraw >= NUM_DRAW_MODES) {
      activeDraw = GRID;
    }
  }
```

If you use C++11's `enum class` then you will have to `static_cast` to and from the int value rather than relying on implicit conversion.

Comment: I cannot make `++activeDraw` compile in C++: ` error: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'drawMode')`, either in C++11 or even 03.

Comment: Yes that was my problem as well Jean. What I was missing were the static casts to int and back in order to + operator work like this: activeDraw = static_cast<drawMode>(static_cast<int>(activeDraw) + 1);

Comment: This should be implemented as an overloaded `operator++(drawMode)` and `operator++(drawMode, int)`.